# Prevent click for the Research Link let others work

Tags: jquery

I have a menu that when you mouse over then the submenu appears. but I want the prevent the #research link being clicked so I used the jquery below. But this prevents my 'My Aplication' link being clicked too. Can someone help me out?

**JQUERY**

```
$('#research a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li id="research"><a href="#">Research</a>
    <div class="submenu" style="display:none">
    <div class="submenuLeft">
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Application</li>
            <li><a href="/research/application">My Application</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--submenuLeft-->
    </div><!--submenu-->
</li>
```

Comment: The reason is because `$('#research a')` will select **all** links that are members of the element with the id `research`, not just the first one directly after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$('#research > a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `>` is preferred to ensure that the a is a direct descendent of the `li#research`.

The `first()` is already mentioned by @algorhythm.

Changing that slightly to below snippet will be more faster in execution.

```
$('#research a:first-child').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: whats the > symbol mean within a selector?

Comment: It selects only a direct child. `$('#research a:first-child')` might be a better selector, in case he adds another link at that level.

Answer (score 5):

Give your link a class-attrbute e.g. 'hide'

```
$('#research a.hide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or use method [.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('#research a').first().click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or

```
$('#research a[href="#"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or better something like this

```
$('#research a').filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.text().toLowerCase() == 'research';
}).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Rather than .first(), use the `:first-child` pseudo-class selector: `$('#research a:first-child')` for better performance.

Comment: @crush thx, that a good point, but can you possibly explain why the performance is better?

Comment: Well, it's $() vs $().first(). 1 function call vs 2 function calls.

Comment: @crush Yes, and even $('.some:first-child') should be faster than $('.some') because after finding the first node the loop can stop and don't have to select further elements, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right - a more important note than the one I made even!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, makes sure only the one with the # is applied to in case you have multiple links with `href=#`

```
$('#research a:[href="#"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I second this - it's the most succinct answer and will prevent any links with the `href='#'` being clicked; should you need to add any more under `#research`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<li id="research"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Research</a>
```